# Is there a way to see if answers to my question has been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Is there a way to see if answers to my question has been deleted ?

I'm only able to see the edits to my question by clicking on the time of the last edit, but I don't see a similar feature for the answers.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably not very helpful, but you can see the last activity in the list of questions (sorted by "active"). If you see there a user, who was last to modify the post, and you don't see any activity by that user in your question and the answers to your question, then it is probable because he deleted his answer.

Comment: What would you do with that information?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With 10K rep you will be able to see this on any question (including your own). With less than 10K rep the only deleted answers you can see are your own answers.

Answer (score 3):

To view the **own** deleted answer there is no such privilege require, while in other cases only two type of users can view any deleted answer, who can either moderator ( highest privilege user ) or user with 10K reputation.